# Display users from user profile

Tags: user-profile

I need to display all the users from the User Profile Service with some basic properties like name email in a web part in sharepoint 2013.

Please help on this.

Comment: using what? c# or js?

Answer (score 1):

Use search to get all the users. Make sure you define some kind of sorting.

C# on-prem sample:

```
private static DataTable GetPeople(SPSite spSite, string queryText)
{

    var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(spSite)
    {
        QueryText = queryText,
        KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords,
        HiddenConstraints = "scope:" + "\"People\"",                
        ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults,
        RankingModelId = "D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1"
    };

    keywordQuery.RowLimit = 200;

    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("UserProfile_GUID");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("PreferredName");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("WorkEmail");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("PictureURL");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("MobilePhone");            

    ResultTableCollection resultTableCol = keywordQuery.Execute();
    ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCol[ResultType.RelevantResults];

    var resultsDataTable = new DataTable
    {
        TableName = "Results"
    };

    resultsDataTable.Load(resultTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    return resultsDataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Search Results web part.

Edit the web part, click `Change Query`. In the `Select a Query` dropdown, select `Local People Results (System)`. In the `Query Text` box, enter `contentclass=people`. Go to the Test tab to make sure that your query will populate the results you're looking for, then save everything.

[image: People Search]

You can also add additional filters, if you'd like. You can also add refiners, and sort. Just play around with the setting a bit.